# hyperlink text on a canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create links in HTML canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215841/create-links-in-html-canvas)

I have filled text in a html5 canvas using

```
window.onload = function() {
            var theCanvas = document.getElementById('Canvas1');
            if (theCanvas && theCanvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
                if (ctx) {
                                                ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";

                    ctx.fillText("INDEX",325,105);
                    }}}
```

Now i want to hyperlink whatever text i have entered how do i do that? Thank you

Comment: Cavas is a tool for drawing, it isn't well suited to creating hypertext.

Comment: so there is no way to do it??

Comment: You certainly can't use a regular link. You could probably rig up a pile of JS to do it. Canvas just isn't a good starting point for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Short of creating a system that parses the text for hyperlinks, measures its position and checks for clicks on it, you can't.