# How to create hyperlink in Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, titanium, html5-canvas

I am able to add given text into canvas using jcollage ( http://radikalfx.com/files/collage-with-text/demo.html) plugin but when user entered a text such as: www.example.com, it should automatically be converted to a hyperlink.

Some body please help how to figure that user entered text is hyperlink and how to find hyperlink position because i am converting that canvas as image and showing in web view in Titanium there also if user clicked on hyperlink i have to transfer it to that page.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this: [Create links in HTML canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215841/create-links-in-html-canvas). Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not as simple as you might think.

The canvas doesn't actually "store" the text, it's just a grid of pixels. It's not aware of elements drawn on the canvas or anything. As such, the canvas can't "hyperlink" a text element.

One of the options would be to add a `click` event listener to the canvas, get the `x/y` of the event, and if you hit the text, redirect to the url. To do this you would need to keep track of the text's position (rotation?) and size, manually.

Another, possibly easier option, would be to simply add a element on top of the image that contains the text. Then, you can simply add a hyperlink.

**[Working example of a link overlaying the canvas](http://jsbin.com/udukim/1/edit)**

Comment: Actually i need to create magazine app in Titanium using that canvas image. So i am having lot of confusions in mind to proceed further.

Comment: I can't say I know anything about titanium, but I do believe the easiest thing to do would be to overlay actual text, then...

Comment: In my case this overlaying wont work any way thanks for you help

Comment: Can you explain why not? Maybe I can help.

Comment: In my case user will only gives the text and i need to find out where he is given hyper link (i.e., like example.com) and then when click on that link only i need to transfer and one more thing in titanium i am not using canvas just getting the image given by canvas.

Comment: Ah, Yea, the example wasn't a full functionality, it was only to demonstrate how to overlay a link. You'll have to do the other logic (Checking if the text's a link, positioning, etc), yourself...

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible.

In order to make a "hyperlink", you would have to create your own box, fill it with text, keep tabs of its position (in 3D -- to make sure that it's not covered by another layer), style the text in a specific format, and THEN check to make sure that if a person clicks on the canvas, and the click happened on the box, AND the box was the top-most layer, that you'd set the user's `window.location` to be equal to whatever they typed in (if you validated that it was, indeed a correctly-written URL).

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. First, you say "It's not possible", then you explain how to do it.

Comment: @Cerbrus A "Hyperlink", which is actually a DOM-embedded, user-clickable object is not possible at all. You have to manually create and maintain a virtual, off-DOM JS object, and do videogame-esque collision/selection detection on it. That's an exceptionally far cry from `<a href="//site.com">link</a>`. Programming in state-changes (like links which grow underlines or change colour on-hover/click/visited) would become stupid-painful, to lock all of that functionality down. You'd also have to start managing the CSS of the canvas, based on the collision detection, to get the finger-pointer...

Comment: It is possible. Simple, even.
`<canvas></canvas><a href="//site.com">link</a>` <-- Position that link to overlay the canvas at your desired location, and voilá! a clickable hyperlink on top of the canvas.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure, you can happily do a `position:absolute`, but that would make something like applying physics, or applying collision-detection, or per-pixel modification (or `.requestFullScreen`, or game-controller support, etc) much, much more difficult/impossible. Perhaps that's not the fundamental goal here, but there must be a reason it's going to be 100% canvas, and not just DOM.