# Rotation wheel with 12 fields like a chart

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have to create a rotation wheel with 12 fields like in the image below link :http://www.resilienciacomunitaria.org/
How i create through which approach?
I used canvas for this but not successful i used d3.js svg but not successful .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" 
style="background-color:#ffff">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height /2; //400
//alert(radius);

//draw a circle again and agian 
  ctx.translate(radius, radius);


    radius =radius*0.85;
    setInterval(drawCircle, 50);
    function drawCircle() {
        var pos = .01;
        var length = 100;
        var width = 40;
            drawFace(ctx, radius);
            drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width); 


 }
function drawFace(ctx,radius){

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ffff';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke(); 


      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
       ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.lineWidth = 50;  
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

}
function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {

  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 30;


    ctx.moveTo(-radius,0);
    ctx.lineTo(radius, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(-radius,150);
    ctx.lineTo(radius, -150);
    ctx.moveTo(-radius,-150);
    ctx.lineTo(radius, 150);
    ctx.moveTo(-radius,380);
    ctx.lineTo(radius, -380);
    ctx.moveTo(-radius,-380);
    ctx.lineTo(radius, 380);
    ctx.moveTo(0, -radius);
    ctx.lineTo(0, radius);

    ctx.stroke();
/*
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
    ctx.font="20px Verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText("Explore Zero",180,180);

    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';*/
    ctx.rotate(-pos);

}


</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both canvas and d3 should be able to do this fairly easily. Show your code and let's try to fix it.

Comment: put the image on the page and just rotate it. example-CSS: transform: rotate(7deg); only you should do this in javascript..

Comment: @zoran404, I think the inside spike indicator needs to remain motionless while the wheel spins. But yes, 2 separate image elements with one rotating should do the trick. You should code it up and post it as an answer ;-)

Comment: @markE i want to use canvas for this and spokes in the image should be straight

Comment: @markE i used the above code but i fail to lable text and color

Comment: @markE in this code i used broad line may i have to use arc ?

Comment: @markE need the straight lines and labels too please if you can help me out .

Comment: http://www.explorezero.com/ i want the 12 spokes but should be straight like in the url and label on them i found the example now so i used the link now @markE thanks

Comment: @markE i decided to go with the new code i updated here please help me out

Comment: Ouch! I used up my available time helping with your first design. Sorry :-/ You might post another question with your new design and see if someone has available time.

Comment: its ok thanks markE you helped me a lot,i have no permission to ask more question

Comment: @markE can you please look through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Here's code to get you started:**

*You can style it to your specific needs*

- Create an in-memory canvas containing your wheel.
- Create an in-memory canvas containing your spike-indicator.
- Rotate the canvas and draw the wheel on the main canvas.
- Draw the indicator on the main canvas.
- Change the rotation angle for the next loop.
- Repeat, repeat, repeat using requestAnimationFrame.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var myData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=150;

var wheel=document.createElement('canvas');
var wheelCtx=wheel.getContext('2d');

var indicator=document.createElement('canvas');
var indicatorCtx=indicator.getContext('2d');


var angle=PI2-PI2/4;

var myColor = [];
for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){ myColor.push(randomColor()); }

makeWheel();
makeIndicator();

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function makeWheel(){

  wheel.width=wheel.height=radius*2+2;
  wheelCtx.lineWidth=1;
  wheelCtx.font='24px verdana';
  wheelCtx.textAlign='center';
  wheelCtx.textBaseline='middle';

  var cx=wheel.width/2;
  var cy=wheel.height/2;

  var sweepAngle=PI2/myData.length;
  var startAngle=0;
  for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){

    // calc ending angle based on starting angle
    var endAngle=startAngle+sweepAngle;

    // draw the wedge
    wheelCtx.beginPath();
    wheelCtx.moveTo(cx,cy);
    wheelCtx.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle,false);
    wheelCtx.closePath();
    wheelCtx.fillStyle=myColor[i];
    wheelCtx.strokeStyle='black';
    wheelCtx.fill();
    wheelCtx.stroke();

    // draw the label
    var midAngle=startAngle+(endAngle-startAngle)/2;
    var labelRadius=radius*.85;
    var x=cx+(labelRadius)*Math.cos(midAngle);
    var y=cy+(labelRadius)*Math.sin(midAngle);
    wheelCtx.fillStyle='gold';
    wheelCtx.fillText(myData[i],x,y);
    wheelCtx.strokeText(myData[i],x,y);

    // increment angle
    startAngle+=sweepAngle;
  }


}

function makeIndicator(){

  indicator.width=indicator.height=radius+radius/10;
  indicatorCtx.font='18px verdana';
  indicatorCtx.textAlign='center';
  indicatorCtx.textBaseline='middle';
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle='skyblue';
  indicatorCtx.strokeStyle='blue';
  indicatorCtx.lineWidth=1;

  var cx=indicator.width/2;
  var cy=indicator.height/2;

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.moveTo(cx-radius/8,cy);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx,cy-indicator.height/2);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx+radius/8,cy);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle='skyblue'
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.arc(cx,cy,radius/3,0,PI2);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.fillStyle='blue';
  indicatorCtx.fillText('Prizes',cx,cy);
}


function animate(time){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.translate(cw/2,ch/2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(wheel,-wheel.width/2,-wheel.height/2);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.translate(-cw/2,-ch/2);
  ctx.drawImage(indicator,cw/2-indicator.width/2,ch/2-indicator.height/2)
  angle+=PI2/360;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you please give one more favour ,i want the spokes of the wheel to be straight and also the label(text written in it like prize),in above code i used broad line like that

Comment: You're welcome. Ouch! The new image example you give is very unlike your original image! The new image requires a totally different answer!! So **briefly**...Create a clipping path using your circle. Then draw 6 rotated lines with a large lineWidth that cross the circle's centerpoint. That will give you the straight spokes. You can draw text along the spokes using fillText  with textAlign='center' & textBaseline='middle' while each spoke rotation is still in effect.

Comment: yes i am facing two problems 1.text in the spokes 2. the 12 straight lines actually after some searching i get this example

Comment: Ok, well...good luck in deciding on a final design! if you're still having coding problems you might ask a new question about the design you finally decide on.

Comment: i did some code @markE  as you explained above and facing the text (complete lable like prize ) problem and please review the above updated code also

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the "wheel" image on the website and just rotate it.

```
document.getElementById("TheImage").style.transform = "rotate("+YourAngle+"deg)";
```

Also you will need to put the "pointer" image on top of "wheel" image. (you will not rotate this one)

Comment: @zoran404, upvote for a good answer. The OP really should have mentioned the need for dynamic labels in their question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fiddle written in 20 minutes, hope it helps.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
var lines = new Array();
lines[0] = new Array();
lines[0] = ["Prize 1","#000000"];
lines[1] = new Array();
lines[1] = ["Prize 2","#ffff00"];
lines[2] = new Array();
lines[2] = ["Prize 3","#ff00ff"];
lines[3] = new Array();
lines[3] = ["Prize 4","#00ffff"];
lines[4] = new Array();
lines[4] = ["Prize 5","#00ff00"];

var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;
var angle = 360 / lines.length; //to see how far apart the lines need to be
var angle_offset = 0; //this will determine the spinning
var angle_speed = 1; //degrees per cycle
var center_offset = 20; //the radius of your spinner in the middle

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    angle_offset+=angle_speed;
    ctx.font="20px Verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
    for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle=lines[i][1];
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        ctx.rotate((angle * i + angle_offset) * TO_RADIANS);
        //Here you can also decorate with boxes and stuff
        ctx.fillText(lines[i][0],center_offset,0); 
        ctx.restore();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Niddro it help me in writing text but not exactly I want to create the structure like in the above URL http://www.resilienciacomunitaria.org/ its in flash I need to so it in canvas or svg or by CSS any meAns

Comment: I took me some time to chance the code a bit, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/6xv38qtz/

Comment: thanks its quite similar , is it possible to make it responsive and i need 12 spokes and text  on outer circle ?

Comment: Here is how you add links in canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215841/create-links-in-html-canvas. You have to check where the user is clicking and determine which, if any, spoke was there at the time of the click.

Comment: is it possible to make it responsive?

Comment: Resonsive to clicks? Yes, that's possible, check the link in my comment above.

Comment: responsive for mobile devices and text on the outer circle

Comment: In order to make it responsive for mobile deviced, you'll need to use [onTouch-commands](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml) instead of onclick. To make the text bend, I didn't immediately find a javascript solution but I'd use the [same technique as used for CSS](http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/). Remember that Stackoverflow.com is not meant to get ppl to do all your work for you, only to solve certain problems ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70691/discussion-between-gaurav-parashar-and-niddro).