# Chart.js turn labels into links

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm not sure this is possible without doing something along the line of: [Create links in HTML canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215841/create-links-in-html-canvas) but let's make sure.

Is there a way to (relatively) simply turn Chart.js labels into links? The chart in question is the radar chart: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart 
(So far I've been using the legend for that, works fine with a little library modification, but now I should use the labels themselves.)

Comment: I believe you would have to go with the way that is in the link you provided. It's because Chart.js uses the canvas element do draw everything including its labels.

Comment: Even that solution wouldn't be good to me because, if I understood correctly, I could only have links that look like links - full urls, instead of user-friendly labels with href not visible to average user.

Comment: A slight alteration can fix that. You could display one text but store a link corresponding with that text, when the item is clicked go to the corresponding link location.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the click event and then loop through all the pointLabels check if the click is in that box. If this is the case you get the corresponding label from the array containing all the labels.

Then you can open use `window.location = link` or `window.open(link)` to go to your link.

Example that searches the color on google on click:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (evt, activeEls, chart) => {
      const {
        x,
        y
      } = evt;
      let index = -1;

      for (let i = 0; i < chart.scales.r._pointLabelItems.length; i++) {
        const {
          bottom,
          top,
          left,
          right
        } = chart.scales.r._pointLabelItems[i];

        if (x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom) {
          index = i;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (index === -1) {
        return;
      }

      const clickedLabel = chart.scales.r._pointLabels[index];

      window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=color%20${clickedLabel}`); // Blocked in stack snipet. See fiddle
      console.log(clickedLabel)
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/fnqr4c7j/22/

Answer (score 0):

It's really late but [bencekd's answer to "Add Link to X-Label Chart.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925791/) worked for me.

My project uses the old Chart.js v1 and it's for a bar chart, not radar. You'll have to modify it accordingly as per the current version Chart.js. I don't see why it shouldn't work for a radar with a little refactoring.

Code (their provided [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencekd/1u5nuvc5/5/), one minor change by me, comments by "/*" indicate my lines):

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random()*100)
};

var barChartData = {
    labels :
    ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
    responsive : true
});

$("#canvas").click(
    function(evt){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        // from the endPoint we get the end of the bars area
        var base = myBar.scale.endPoint;
        var height = myBar.chart.height;
        var width = myBar.chart.width;
        // only call if event is under the xAxis
        if(evt.pageY > base){
            // how many xLabels we have
            var count = myBar.scale.valuesCount;
            var padding_left = myBar.scale.xScalePaddingLeft;
            var padding_right = myBar.scale.xScalePaddingRight;
            // calculate width for each label
            var xwidth = (width-padding_left-padding_right)/count;
            // determine what label were clicked on AND PUT IT INTO bar_index
            var bar_index = (evt.offsetX - padding_left) / xwidth;
            // don't call for padding areas
            if(bar_index > 0 & bar_index < count){
                bar_index = parseInt(bar_index);
                // either get label from barChartData
                //console.log("barChartData:" + barChartData.labels[bar_index]);
                // or from current data
                /* barChartData didn't work for me, so disabled above */
                var ret = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < myBar.datasets[0].bars.length; i++) {
                    ret.push(myBar.datasets[0].bars[i].label)
                };
                console.log("current data:" + ret[bar_index]);
                // based on the label you can call any function
                /* I made to go where I wanted here with a window.location.href
           and taking the label (ret[bar_index]) as an argument */
            }
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <div style="width: 50%">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
        </div>
    <div>
    Click on the x labels!
    </div>
    <div id="hello">
    </div>
```