# How to make labels clickable in angular-chart

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am trying to add a click handler to the **labels** of a chart that was rendered by angular-chart.

Is there a way to add an specific event handler or use the existing chart-click directive?

At the moment the chart-click directive is returning the MouseEvent object only.

After reading the docs I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918750/add-link-to-x-label-chart-js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getPointsAtEvent` event to detect the closest point on the graph, and retrieve its associated label. The problem is that you cannot detect a click directly on a label element as it as drawn as text in the `<canvas>` element.

Demo :

```js
angular.module( 'app', ['tc.chartjs']);

angular.module( 'app' )
.controller( 'AppController', function( $scope ) {
    
    $scope.chart;
    
    $scope.chartClick = function( event ) {
    
      var pointsClicked = $scope.chart.getPointsAtEvent(event); 
     if (!pointsClicked || pointsClicked.length == 0)
       return;
    
      if (pointsClicked[0].label)
        $scope.label = 'You clicked on ' + pointsClicked[0].label;
    };

    
    // Chart.js Data
    $scope.data = {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'My First dataset',
          fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
          strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
          pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
      ]
    };

    // Chart.js Options
    $scope.options =  {
      // Sets the chart to be responsive
      responsive: true
    };

    
});

/**
 * tc-angular-chartjs - v1.0.9 - 2014-10-14
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Carl Craig <carlcraig@3c-studios.com>
 * Dual licensed with the Apache-2.0 or MIT license.
 */
!function(){"use strict";function a(a){return new a}function b(a){return new a("line")}function c(a){return new a("bar")}function d(a){return new a("radar")}function e(a){return new a("polararea")}function f(a){return new a("pie")}function g(a){return new a("doughnut")}function h(){return function(a){function b(b,d,e){var f,g=d[0].getContext("2d"),h=new Chart(g),i=!1,j=!1,k=!1,l=null;for(var m in e)"chartLegend"===m?i=!0:"chart"===m?k=!0:"autoLegend"===m&&(j=!0);b.$watch("data",function(e){if(e){if(f&&f.destroy(),a)f=h[c(a)](b.data,b.options);else{if(!b.type)throw"Error creating chart: Chart type required.";f=h[c(b.type)](b.data,b.options)}i&&(b.legend=f.generateLegend()),j&&(l&&l.remove(),angular.element(d[0]).after(f.generateLegend()),l=angular.element(d[0]).next()),k&&(b.chart=f)}},!0)}function c(a){var b=a.toLowerCase();switch(b){case"line":return"Line";case"bar":return"Bar";case"radar":return"Radar";case"polararea":return"PolarArea";case"pie":return"Pie";case"doughnut":return"Doughnut";default:return a}}var d={restrict:"A",scope:{data:"=chartData",options:"=chartOptions",type:"@chartType",legend:"=chartLegend",chart:"=chart"},link:b};return d}}function i(){function a(a,b){a.$watch("legend",function(a){a&&b.html(a)},!0)}var b={restrict:"A",scope:{legend:"=chartLegend"},link:a};return b}angular.module("tc.chartjs",[]).directive("tcChartjs",a).directive("tcChartjsLine",b).directive("tcChartjsBar",c).directive("tcChartjsRadar",d).directive("tcChartjsPolararea",e).directive("tcChartjsPie",f).directive("tcChartjsDoughnut",g).directive("tcChartjsLegend",i).factory("TcChartjsFactory",h),a.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"],b.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"],c.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"],d.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"],e.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"],f.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"],g.$inject=["TcChartjsFactory"]}();

angular.bootstrap( document, [ 'app' ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppController">

  <canvas tc-chartjs-line chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend ng-click="chartClick($event)" chart="chart"></canvas>
  <h3 ng-bind="label"></h3>
  
</div>
```