# Chartjs 2.9.4 - clickable label

Tags: javascript, chart.js, typeerror

I'm trying to make linkable label to redirect to a page when clicked (i use this snippet: [Add Link to X-Label Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918750/add-link-to-x-label-chart-js/48710793#48710793)). I'm using the 2.9.4 version of ChartJS.

This is my code:

```
    var ctx =  document.getElementById("barChart-mostSold").getContext('2d');
this.chartmostSold =new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: {{listTopIssuerSoldLabel | tojson }},
      datasets: [
        {
          data: {{listTopIssuerSoldValue | tojson }}
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
    events: ["mousemove", "mouseout", "click", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"],
    onClick: function(e, data) {
            var ctx = $("#barChart-mostSold")[0].getContext("2d");
            var base = this.chart.chartArea.bottom;
            var height = this.chart.chart.height;
            var width = this.chart.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].width;
            var offset = $('#chartmostSold').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if(e.pageY > base + offset){
                var count = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].ticks.length;
                var padding_left = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].paddingLeft;
                var padding_right = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].paddingRight;
                var xwidth = (width-padding_left-padding_right)/count;
                // don't call for padding areas
                var bar_index = (e.offsetX - padding_left - this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].width) / xwidth;
                if(bar_index > 0 & bar_index < count){
                    bar_index = Math.floor(bar_index);
                    console.log(bar_index);
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at tn.onClick ((index):1141)
at tn.handleEvent (VM64 Chart.min.js:7)
at tn.eventHandler (VM64 Chart.min.js:7)
at n (VM64 Chart.min.js:7)
at HTMLCanvasElement.Se.<computed> (VM64 Chart.min.js:7)
```

Comment: #chartmostSold is hidden?

Comment: @A.T. No, it's a simple canvas in div:
            <canvas id="barChart-mostSold"></canvas>

Comment: could it be possible that your script trigger before displaying element on DOM?

Comment: @A.T. I just tried to use outside my function "$(document).ready(function(){ ...}); " but the error it's the same when the page is loaded, I click on label and this happen: https://i.imgur.com/eMnyQHr.png

Comment: I see. You got a typo. The id is barChart-mostSold as per your comment, not chartmostSold as in the image.

Comment: Thank you @A.T. it works. But only when I click on bar not in label! Why? How can i swap it?

Comment: If user clicks on the x axis label, then how to get the label value