# Add Href to canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I am using [HexagonTools](https://github.com/mpalmerlee/HexagonTools) to draw hexagon using canvas.

I need to add an href link to elements of canvas.

I have tried this code:

```
function drawHexGrid()
{
var linkText="http://stackoverflow.com";
var linkX=5;
var linkY=15;
var linkHeight=10;
var linkWidth;
var inLink = false;

    var grid = new HT.Grid(800, 600);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("hexCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    for(var h in grid.Hexes)
    {
        grid.Hexes[h].draw(ctx);
        linkWidth=ctx.measureText(linkText).width;          
             canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);

    }
}
```

But this is not working, I need a simple example on how to develop this, I have already  looked at this [SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215841/create-links-in-html-canvas)
But I couldn't develop it

Comment: You would need to detect if the mouse is over desired element and then something like `var mouseClicked = function() { if (mouseIsOverTheElement) { location.replace }};` I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test which hexagon you mouse clicked using `context.isPointInPath`.

- Listen for mousedown events
- In mousedown, fetch the mouseX, mouseY
- Recreate each of your hex paths (no need to actually stroke/fill them).
- For each hex, use `.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)` to see if the mouse clicked in this hex.
- If you find a clicked hex, use `window.open(theUrl, '_blank')` to navigate to its associated url.

In Hexagon Tools, each hex has a `points` property which you can use to receate each of your hex paths.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var hexes=[];
hexes.push({
  points:[{x:57.5,y:63},{x:42.5,y:63},{x:35,y:50},{x:42.5,y:37},{x:57.5,y:37},{x:65,y:50}],
  url:'http://stackoverflow.com',
});

draw();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

function draw(){
  for(var i=0;i<hexes.length;i++){
    var h=hexes[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(h.points[0].x,h.points[0].y);
    for(var j=1;j<h.points.length;j++){
      ctx.lineTo(h.points[j].x,h.points[j].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  for(var i=0;i<hexes.length;i++){
    var h=hexes[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(h.points[0].x,h.points[0].y);
    for(var j=1;j<h.points.length;j++){
      ctx.lineTo(h.points[j].x,h.points[j].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    //if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){ window.open(h.url, '_blank'); }
    if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){ alert('Navigate to: '+h.url); }
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click in the hexagon to navigate to Stackoverflow.com</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Your example is working (y), but I I can't integrate it in the lib that I am using. Thank you