# linking a website to an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink

So I am using this to display images on a site

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

images();
function images() {
image1 = new Image();

image1.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7PP1DeqGfPdu-12ULf1baVkQ7B-
lZvbjef7uPg5ZWOs5OX_4psOdKJO8RpgaXKhN9OlC=w200-h300';

image1.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(image1, 10, 10, 220, 300);
}
```

But now I've decided I want to link a site to each of those images when they are clicked.

Initially, I thought I could just use the normal href way, but that cant be done in this case. Is there another way I can set this up?

Comment: Might want to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217714/1926621

Answer (score 1):

catch the click event and redirect to the page/site you want by window.location='https://yourwebpage.com'

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answer you can create click events by adding event listeners.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

canvas.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // User clicked on canvas
    window.location = 'https://google.com/'
});
```